# Junit CXF REST API and rollback test data

Tags: java, rest, junit, cxf, spring-test

I would like to write Junit test cases for REST API. The APIs are written using CXF framework.

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**spring-config.xml:**

```
<jaxrs:server id="/SomeAction" address="/SomeAction" staticSubresourceResolution="true" publishedEndpointUrl="${endpointUrl}/SomeAction">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="SomeWebService"></ref>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider"></ref>
        <ref bean="exceptionMapper"></ref>
    </jaxrs:providers>

</jaxrs:server>
```

**Webservice:**

```
@Override
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/doSome")
public WSResponse doSome(WSRequest request) {
//Do Some operation
}
```

**Junit**

```
@Test
public void testDoSome()
        throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(
            post("/SomeAction/doSome").contentType(contentType))
            .andExpect(status().isFound());
}
```

I can write Junit test cases for simple REST API and rollback the data after test is done using spring test. But I couldn't write when CXF framework is involved. I have two issues here.

- The above Junit code returns 404 response instead of 200.
- I want to
     rollback the data when test is done

Pleas help me to resolve the issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name implies, the *Spring MVC Test Framework* is for testing Spring MVC Web and Spring MVC REST applications.

You are writing a CXF REST application which is based on JAX-RS.

Spring MVC REST is not an implementation of JAX-RS.

It is therefore not possible to test a JAX-RS application with Spring MVC Test (i.e., `MockMvc`).

To test your JAX-RS endpoints, you will need to use a testing framework with dedicated support for JAX-RS. For example, you may want to use the [JAX-RS Testing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAXRS+Testing) support from CXF, or you can Google "jax-rs testing" to find other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Local Transport from CXF:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/Local+Transport